# Convert to Decimal using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to select the value of Sales from my Class QCA. I am using linq to query a collection of QCA's. I want the most recent one by Date When I try this code I get errors telling me It cannot convert IEnumerable to decimal.
Where am I going wrong?

```
SalesTotal = (from q in QuickCreditAssessments orderby q.FinancialsDate ascending
                              select q.Sales).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a single don't use `Take` but `First/FirstOrDefault/Single/SingleOrDefault`:

```
decimal salesTotal = (from q in QuickCreditAssessments 
                      orderby q.FinancialsDate ascending 
                      select q.Sales)
    .Skip(1)  // now you get the second to last by Date
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

As an aside, if you want the "most recent one by Date" you should use `descending`.

Comment: ... and probably not use `.Skip(1)` as that would mean they get the second one available.

Comment: @JonHanna: you're right, i've added a comment at the `Skip`, maybe OP wants the second to last. It's also worth noting that he also gets none if there is no or only one record. None with `FirstOrDefault` means `0` because that's the default value for `decimal`.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. Thank you. This works exactly. Also, descending is what I needed as well. It's like you read my mind. : )

Comment: EB, it might be worth taking a read through [the documentation of the queryable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [the very similar enumerable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the detailed descriptions of all these methods.

Answer (score 2):

`Take` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, instead of Take in your case i'd use `FirstOrDefault()`, like this:

```
SalesTotal = (from q in QuickCreditAssessments orderby q.FinancialsDate ascending
                              select q.Sales).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```